# How to access a control in an .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, radiobuttonlist

I attach event with `radiobuttonlist` in code behind page, radiobuttonlist is inside   a
`listview` .When I run program it generates an error :
***"object referance not set to instant of object"***

**.aspx code:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
  <ItemTemplate>
       <tr><td>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radiobuttonlist4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 

        RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="selected" Width="240px">
    <asp:ListItem  Value="agree"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="disagree"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="strongagree"></asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="strongdisagree"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>




</td>
       </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

**.aspx.cs Code**

```
assessdal s = new assessdal();

ListView1.DataSource = s.showop1();
ListView1.DataBind();
RadioButtonList list=  ListView1.FindControl("radiobuttonlist4") as RadioButtonList;

list.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(handle);

public void handle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = "y";      
}
```

Comment: Please format your code, in which template of the listview is the RadioButtonList?

Comment: soory,there is radiobuttonlist control in .aspx code ,during copying code, it was missed..

Comment: @user1405508: Why don't you edit your question properly? So others can help !!

Comment: @user1405508: Where do you want to find your RadioButtonList? You have shown your codebehind where is this code?

Answer (score 1):

First, i fixed a ton of typos in your code.

Second, it's not finding it because `FindControl` is being called on `ListView1`, not the page (or the control hierarchy in which it exists) and `FindControl` only looks within that instance's child controls.

Try `Page.FindControl("radiobuttonlist4")` to find it in the page.

Comment: but radiobuttonlist is in listview .so we find it in listview

Comment: but radiobuttonlist is in listview .so we find it in listview

Answer (score 0):

You should  attach the event handler declaratively on the aspx, that's the easiest way.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radiobuttonlist4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
     RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="selected" 
     Width="240px">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Since the `ListView` can contain multiple items, the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) of a control in it's `Itemtemplate` is not the `ListView`, but the `ListViewItem`. That ensures that every control gets a unique id on clientside.

So you can find your `RadioButtonList` in the button's click event handler in this way:

```
var button = (Button)sender;
var item = (ListViewItem)button.NamingContainer;
var radiobuttonlist4 = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("radiobuttonlist4");
```

If you want to "find" the RadioButtonList in it's `SelectedIndexChanged` event, simply cast the `sender` argument accordingingly (`var rbl = (RadioButtonList)sender;`).